# use ternary operator in *ngFor in Angular

Tags: angular

Here's how I'm iterating the array items

```
  <div *ngFor="let car of cars">
    {{car}}
  </div>
```

I want to add a link to an array item after performing a checking using ternary operator something like

```
{{car === 'Jeep' ?
    <a href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/" target="_">car</a> 
    : car }}
```

Is this even possible? Could anyone please help?

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-ritchie-z0dws?file=/src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `*ngIf ... else`

```
  <div *ngFor="let car of cars">
    <a *ngIf="car === 'Jeep'; else other_content" href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/" target="_">{{car}}</a> 
    <ng-template #other_content>{{car}}</ng-template>
  </div>
```

Comment: Perfect, that was it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
<div>
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <div *ngFor="let car of cars">
      <a *ngIf="car === 'Audi'" href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/" target="_">{{car}}</a> 
      <a *ngIf="car === 'BMW'" href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/" target="_">{{car}}</a> 
      <a *ngIf="car === 'Jeep'" href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/" target="_">{{car}}</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```